# Can I update Timber and or Twig?

Tags: wordpress, twig, php-8, timber

I took over a site using Twig 1.24.1 from 2016.

It also has some version of Timber baked into an old Sage theme. There is no Timber plugin.

If I update to PHP 8, I get a fatal error.

If I install the Timber plugin, I get a fatal error.

Is there some way to update Timber and Twig to work with PHP 8? I have found zero helpful info or docs about doing this here, at Github, at Upstatement, or in Google.

I also tried downloading Twig and swapping out some files and directories. That also failed hard. So I know how to break this site... but I'd really like to get it updated and stable.

Here's the error if it helps - which goes away in PHP 7.4.x

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_key_exists(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, Timber\Menu given in /nas/content/live/site/wp-content/themes/wobs-theme/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:533\nStack trace:\n#0 /nas/content/live/site/wp-content/themes/wobs-theme/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(403) : eval()'d code(23): Twig_Template->getAttribute(Object(Timber\Menu), 'get_items', Array)\n#1 /nas/content/live/site/wp-content/themes/wobs-theme/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(387): __TwigTemplate_eada0446f028acb9eb859e593a68397ec9225f348f46a00ab74866dfa38d8f16->doDisplay(Array, Array)\n#2 /nas/content/live/site/wp-content/themes/wobs-theme/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(355): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)\n#3 /nas/content/live/site/wp-content/themes/wobs-theme/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(366): Twig_Template->display(Array)\n#4 /nas/content/live/site/wp-content/themes/wobs-theme/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(347): Twig_Template->render(Array)\n#5 /nas/content/live/site/wp-content/themes/wobs-theme/vendor/timber/timber/lib/Loader.php(72): Twig_Environment->render('header.twig', Array)\n#6 /nas/content/live/site/wp-content/themes/wobs-theme/vendor/timber/timber/lib/Timber.php(281): Timber\Loader->render('header.twig', Array, false, 'default')\n#7 /nas/content/live/site/wp-content/themes/wobs-theme/vendor/timber/timber/lib/Timber.php(317): Timber\Timber::compile('header.twig', Array, false, 'default', true)\n#8 /nas/content/live/site/wp-content/themes/wobs-theme/vendor/timber/timber/lib/Timber.php(332): Timber\Timber::fetch('header.twig', Array, false, 'default')\n#9 /nas/content/live/site/wp-content/themes/wobs-theme/templates/header.php(37): Timber\Timber::render('header.twig', Array)\n#10 /nas/content/live/site/wp-includes/template.php(785): require('/nas/content/li...')\n#11 /nas/content/live/site/wp-includes/template.php(718): load_template('/nas/content/li...', false, Array)\n#12 /nas/content/live/site/wp-includes/general-template.php(204): locate_template(Array, true, false, Array)\n#13 /nas/content/live/site/wp-content/themes/wobs-theme/base-front-page.php(19): get_template_part('templates/heade...')\n#14 /nas/content/live/site/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/nas/content/li...')\n#15 /nas/content/live/site/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/nas/content/li...')\n#16 /nas/content/live/site/index.php(17): require('/nas/content/li...')\n#17 {main}\n thrown in /nas/content/live/site/wp-content/themes/wobs-theme/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php on line 533

Comment: "*I get a fatal error*" - Nobody will be able to help you if you don't post the error. [ask]

Comment: The message I get is "There has been a critical error on this website." The problem is, Timber and Twig are 7 years old, incompatible with PHP8, and there seems to be no way to update them.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error you can see that Twig is loaded from
`/nas/content/live/site/wp-content/themes/wobs-theme/vendor/twig/`

It should be possible to find the entry point in the theme where Twig gets loaded from the vendor folder. If you remove the existing implementation and replace it with your own (as a Wordpress plugin or via composer) you should get it to work. Composer gives you better control in my opinion.